# Problem with displaying number in inner text

Tags: javascript, html, css

newbie here...

I am working on some simple project where I am trying to simulate bank app.

Thing is that when I click on send money button, I want to take value from input value, and then subtract this value from my whole account balance.

Really simple, but after first transaction I get value which I want, but after second time I get innerText displaying "Nan" instead of some number value.

Here it is javascript file, if you can see from this why I get error.
Also here it is html and css if you don't understand what I am talking about.

```
    ////////////////// TOTAL MONEY FROM CARDS ///////////////////////
const totalMoney = document.querySelector(`.totalMoney`);
const allcards = document.querySelectorAll(`.cards`);
let totalMoneyAccount = 0;

allcards.forEach((kartica) => {
  let novacNaKartici = kartica.querySelector(`.novacNaKartici`).innerText;
  novacNaKartici = parseInt(novacNaKartici);
  totalMoneyAccount += novacNaKartici;
  totalMoney.innerText = ` ${replika2} $`;
});

//////////////////////////// TRANSFER MONEY TO SOMEONE /////////////////////////////
const reciver = document.querySelector(`input[name='recivier']`);
let amount = document.querySelector(`input[name='amount']`);
const sendMoneyBtn = document.querySelector(`.sendBtn`);
const transakcijeParent = document.querySelector(`.transakcije`);

sendMoneyBtn.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
  amount = parseInt(amount.value);
  totalMoneyAccount = totalMoneyAccount - amount;

  updateProfile(totalMoneyAccount);
});

function updateProfile(totalMoneyAccount) {
  totalMoney.innerHTML = totalMoneyAccount;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Bank app</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="profile">
        <div class="header">
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> notifications </span>
          <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> search </span>
        </div>
        <div class="person">
          <img src="/img/cost1.jpg" alt="" />
          <p>Random user</p>
          <span class="totalMoney" style="font-size: 20px;"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
          <div class="account flex">
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> manage_accounts </span>
            <p>Accounts</p>
          </div>
          <div class="transactions flex">
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> receipt_long </span>
            <p>Transactions</p>
          </div>
          <div class="bonus flex">
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> star </span>
            <p>Bonus</p>
          </div>
          <div class="invest flex">
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> trending_up </span>
            <p>Investments</p>
          </div>
          <div class="logOut flex">
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> logout </span>
            <p>Log Out</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main">
        <div class="left">
          <div class="naslov">
            <p>Cards</p>
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                add_circle
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="allCards">
              <div class="cards changeJustify">
                <div class="singleCard">
                  <img src="/img/visa.png" alt="" class="changeImg"/>
                </div>
                <div class="opis">
                    <p style="color: grey; font-size:20px">VISA</p>
                    <p style="color: black; font-size:16px" class="balance1 changeBalance">Balance:</p>
                </div>
                <div class="balance">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined  changeSpan dots">
                        more_vert
                    </span>
                    <span style="font-size: 22px; color:grey(59, 59, 59);" class="novacNaKartici">2500$</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="cards changeJustify">
                <div class="singleCard ">
                  <img src="/img/american.jpg" alt="" class="changeImg"/>
                </div>
                <div class="opis ">
                    <p style="color: grey; font-size:20px">VISA</p>
                    <p style="color: grey; font-size:16px" class="balance1 changeBalance">Balance:</p>
                </div>
                <div class="balance ">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined changeSpan dots" >
                        more_vert
                    </span>
                    <span style="font-size: 22px; color:black;" class="novacNaKartici">3500$</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            
          </div>
          <p style="font-size: 30px;
          color: grey;
          font-weight: bold;">Transactions</p>
          <div class="transakcije">
                        
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <p style="font-size: 30px;
          color: grey;
          font-weight: bold;">Transfer money</p>
          <div class="transfer">
            <label for="recivier">Transfer to</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="antonio3101" name="recivier">
            <label for="amount">Amount</label>
            <input type="number" placeholder="$300..." name="amount">
            <button class="sendBtn">Send</button>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #f1f2f6;
}

.profile {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #1d1c57;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
}

.profile .header {
  display: flex;
  padding: 30px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: #7979a6;
}

.profile .header span {
  font-size: 26px;
}

.profile .header span:hover {
  color: white;
}

.profile .person {
  margin-top: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.profile .person img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.profile .person p {
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #c6c5d8;
}

.profile .menu {
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #262467;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #7c7eaa;
}

.profile .flex {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
}

.profile .flex:hover {
  margin-left: 40px;
  color: white;
  transition: ease-in-out;
}

.logOut {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
}

/*-------------------------- KARTICE ----------------------------------------- */

.main .naslov {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.naslov {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.naslov span {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.naslov span:hover {
  color: black;
}

.main .left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.main .left .cards {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.cards {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.cards .singleCard {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.allCards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.cards .singleCard img {
  width: 250px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.cards .opis p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.cards .opis {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.cards .balance {
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/*------------------------------- CHANGE CARD -------------------------------- */

.changeImg {
  height: 50px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.changeSpan {
  display: none;
}

.changeJustify {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.changeBalance {
  display: none;
}

/*-------------------------- TRANSAKCIJE ----------------------------------------- */
.transakcije {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
}

.single-transaction {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.single-transaction img {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.single-transaction .destination {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: rgb(73, 73, 73);
  font-weight: bold;
}

.single-transaction .amount {
  color: rgb(30, 149, 30);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.single-transaction:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

/*-------------------------- RIGHT SECTIONS ----------------------------------------- */

/*-------------------------- TRANSFER MONEY ----------------------------------------- */

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.right .transfer {
  background-color: #1d1c57;
  padding: 50px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.right .transfer input {
  height: 30px;
  font: 24px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.right .transfer label {
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.right .transfer button {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: `totalMoney.innerText = \` ${replika2} $\`;` What is `replika2`?

Comment: I was trying a lot of things, and this is left over from previous actions that I deleted.                                             totalMoney.innerText = ` ${totalMoneyAccount} $`

Comment: At `amount = parseInt(amount.value);` You are overwriting the `amount` variable created at `let amount = document.querySelector(\`input[name='amount']\`);`

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting your `amount` variable (which points to an input element) with the value inputted into said input.
Hence, after the first click you no longer have a reference to the input element: your code tries to read the `value` property of the integer amount of the last transaction. This results in the following evaluation: `parseInt(amount.value)` -> `parseInt(undefined)` -> `NaN`.

Change this code:

```js
sendMoneyBtn.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
  amount = parseInt(amount.value);
  totalMoneyAccount = totalMoneyAccount - amount;

  updateProfile(totalMoneyAccount);
});
```

to something like this:

```js
sendMoneyBtn.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
  const amountValue = parseInt(amount.value);
  totalMoneyAccount = totalMoneyAccount - amountValue;

  updateProfile(totalMoneyAccount);
});
```

Credit to @JohnnyMopp for noticing it first.